# set a phone in full screen for all applications

Tags: android

I am writing an app for allowing kids to access only apps that I want to grant them.
For this, I need to disable the status bar from showing **in all application on device**.
There is such app in the play store: [Link to the app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dreamori.hidebar). 
How can I do it in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create a Kiosk mode for your phone...
you can get the entire procedure here.
It also explains you how to disable status and notification bar expansion in the end.

http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/

You can mix this with 007's answer, and you will get what you need.
I haven't tried it, but this should work. Let me know if you opt for this procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot make kiosk mode since I need to run many apps and kiosk mode is just for one

Comment: You might want to go through the Kiosk apps and kiosk Launcher documentation. 
https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-policy#kiosk-apps

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a good solution at: [this site](http://freaktab.com/forum/tv-player-support/rk3066-devices/mk-models-mk808-802-etc/3925-how-to-hide-status-bar-permanently).
In short: *Navigate to: /system/app and rename systemui.apk to systemui.old
reboot*

I did it and it works great!!!